# I can't load GUI on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: user-interface, ubuntu, nvidia, desktop

Once I rebooted my laptop, and then it has never loaded in GUI mode after that. I can use only tty 1-6, tried reinstall gdm3, lightdm, sddm, purged nvidia drivers and reinstalled. Always as I try to start gui( startx, xinit, systemctl start gdm3) it appears for only severel seconds and crashes. Log file  in Xorg s clear, without (EE).
I also reinstalled ubuntu-gnome-desktop, installed new 4.18.0-16-generic, reinstalled Xorg. Nothing. Is there someone, who can help?

Comment: This is not a programming related question not SO is user support forum. Use askubuntu.com or other more appropriate sites.

Comment: Thank you for help